# How to use lipo command line tool to view my project architectures?

Tags: ios, xcode, lipo

I'm uploading an application to the application loader but i get the error "Apps that include amr64 architecture should include armv7 and armv7s" I have already added these three architectures in the build settings but i'm still getting the same error. Now i want to check the architectures with the lipo command line tool. But i have no idea what to do. Should i use `lipo -info "name of the .app file"` ?

Comment: lifo -info path/to/executable

Comment: What is the executable file? . app or what?

Comment: .app is a folder (the application bundle). Inside that folder is the executable file. It has the same name as the application.

Answer (score 1):

To include all architecture (armv7, armv7s and arm64) check that "Build Active Architecture Only" build setting is set to NO for the Release configuration and in the scheme you are building check that the build configuration is set to 'Release' in the 'Archive' menu.

For how to use lipo command to view your project architectures, if for example your app name is MyApp.app: lipo -info path/to/MyApp.app/MyApp
path/to/MyApp.app/MyApp is the path to the executable of your app